# Cannot scp AWS Lightsail instance - Permission Denied

Tags: scp, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have a AWS Lightsail Bitnami instance. I am able to ssh using the default keypair. However when I try to scp using that same key I am given a 'Permission denied' response. I have tried scp'ing to `/home/bitnami/apps/` and `/opt/bitnami/apps`. I have also tried changing the permissions of my pem file to 400.

```
scp -r -i lightsail-key.pem ~/Local\ Sites/myportfolio/app/ bitnami@34.170.81.72:/opt/bitnami/apps
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the exact error message that you're getting. Don't paraphrase it.

Comment: 'Permission denied' is the exact error message I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change the owner of the target folder. I ssh'd into my instance and ran `sudo chown bitnami TARGETFOLDER`.